# How to parse a file sent to Flask with a POST request into json?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, python-requests

I have a python backend to which i send an xml or h5 files from the front.
Those xml\h5 's are huge lists of datapoints about a patient. I need to extract certain datapoints(subfields of the object) to feed to the next thing in this pipeline, but am not sure how to operate on a "request" file in python so that it is anything close to a json object im familiar with.

I have tried xmltodict library for converting the xml to json

Say, this is more or less how the POSTed file looks like

```
  <patdata>
      <id>MPS_2782</id>
      <lastname/>

....
```

And this is the api

```
from flask import jsonify
import requests, os, json, xmltodict
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)
#VCG scripts are under Software/Matlab/Transfroms

@app.route('/api/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']    
    contents = xmltodict.parse(file)
    # xmltodict is XML to JSON parser
    print(">> The XML contents. <<<\n")
    print(json.loads(jsonify(contents)))
    return jsonify(contents)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

How do i get, say, the patient's id for example from **'file'**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to convert the XML file to dictionary then it's easy to get different attributes from the dictionary.

```
patient_id = contents['patient_id']
print(patient_id)
```

will fetch you the value.